# jQuery creating setting a page and save the changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to develop a setting page in jQuery for an app. in this page i have five check box as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_0" class="custom" value="1"/>
<label for="checkbox1_0">One</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_1" class="custom" value="2"/>
<label for="checkbox1_1">Two</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_2" class="custom" value="3"/>
<label for="checkbox1_2">Three</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_3" class="custom" value="4"/>
<label for="checkbox1_3">Four</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_4" class="custom" value="5"/>
<label for="checkbox1_4">Five</label>
```

now how its possible to have a save button which by clicking,  it saves the status of each check box and the sum of their values. so when the app is closed and then is opened again the changes are saved. for example one may chose check-boxes 1, 2 and 3 which should be saved and checked. also their sum in a constant like A = 1+2+3 = 6; 
i would be really thankful if anyone could help me

Comment: if suppose you are getting A=4 mean how will you find if the checkbox4 is checked or checkbox1 and checkbox3 is checked together?

Comment: i just need the sum values of checked, check-boxes in a constant which should be saved in the app so whenever i need it i could use it. also for a user the checked boxes should saved their status until the user changes it. consider a setting page and a variable which saves the sum of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.custom').click(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            $('.custom:checked').each(function () {
                sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
            });
            alert(sum);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Instead of alert, you may set the sum value to anywhere you need

Comment: thanks a lot that works on sum part .. but how its possible to save the status of check boxes so when i exit the app and run it again i wont lost the changes?

Comment: no you cant save it with your environment which is tagged in your question! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226544/how-to-save-the-input-values-of-an-html-page This link may help you...